# How can i make an icon dynamic with react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, icons, maps

sorry but I just started using react and typescript, I need the icon to change according to the status in the AppointmentType the body color works but the icons don't, can someone show me how to solve the problem?

```
const MapIcon: { [key in AppointmentType]?: React.FC<IIcon> } = {
          Videocall: Camera,
          Expired: Blocked,
          Confirmed: CheckInCircle,
          New: Hourglass,
          Past: CheckInCircle,
        };

        interface IconProps {
          iconType?: React.FC<IIcon>;
          color: string;
        }
        const IconCustom = (props: IconProps) => {
          const { iconType } = props;
          return <div>{iconType}</div>;
        };

        export const AppointmentCard: React.FC<IAppointmentCard> = ({
          name,
          hourLabel,
          type,
          isBonus,
          isModify,
          wasMade,
        }) => {
          const { t } = useTranslation();
          return (
            <Wrapper type={type}>
              <WrapperConfirmsAppointment>
                <IconCustom
                  iconType={MapIcon[type]}
                  color={dateLabelColors[type] || Theme.colors.candy[500]}
                />
                <Body
                  variant={TypographyVariant.SemiBold}
                  size={BodySize.Body60}
                  margin="0 0 0 6px"
                  color={dateLabelColors[type] || Theme.colors.candy[500]}
                >
                  {t('appointment.appointmentProposal.confirmed')}
                </Body>
              </WrapperConfirmsAppointment>
            </Wrapper>
          );
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that the `IconCustom` component just renders the value of the `MapIcon` object instead of an actual icon.
In order to solve it you need to render the icon itself.

There a couple of ways to tackle that:

1. You can alter the `MapIcon` structure to return the rendered icon (assuming that the values are the icons):

```
const MapIcon: { [key in AppointmentType]?: React.FC } = {
  Videocall: <Camera />, 
  Expired: <Blocked />
  ....
};
```

2. Render the returned value as icons:

```
const IconCustom = (props: IconProps) => {
  const { iconType: IconType } = props;
  return <div><IconType /></div>;
};
```

Comment: thanks in the end I solved it const Icon = MapIcon[type]; <Icon/>